# Storing string containing delimiters in contracts - Error: invalid argument 0

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-deployment, nodejs

I have created an array in contract where I'm pushing a string(concatt = IN23450.001 by concatenating 'IN2345' and '0.001').

**Contract**

```
contract BDetails {

struct Details {

    bytes32[] DetailsArray;


}
mapping(string => Details) DetailStructs;

 function appendDetails(string id, bytes32 concatt) payable returns(bool success) {

    DetailStructs[id].DetailsArray.push(concatt); 

}

}
```

While deploying contract I'm getting an error.

> Error: invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal invalid hex string into Go struct field SendTxArgs.data of type hexutil.Bytes

I tried storing string IN23450001 and worked perfectly.

Is it because of the decimal point I'm getting this error?Is there any way to store this string?

Comment: could you provide some contract code for context?

Comment: I'm guessing you're missing `"` around the string - if there's a comma it somehow tries to parse it differently

Comment: I'm concatenating strings...so " " around the string is not necessary right? If I remove the decimal point it works perfectly